# Performence: When animating using requestAnimationFrame, is an interval better than manually calculating the ellasped time?

Tags: javascript, performance, requestanimationframe

In examples I see two different ways how to handle animations using [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame):

#### The first one using `setTimeout()`

```
const e = document.getElementById('e');
let count = 0;

function move(timestamp) {
  e.style.left = ++count + 'px';

  setTimeout(f=>{
    requestAnimationFrame(move);
  }, 200);
};

requestAnimationFrame(move);
```

Try it in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6szbgfba/12/).

#### The second one by calulating the ellapsed time yourself

```
const e = document.getElementById('e');
let count = 0;
let past = null; 

function move(timestamp) {
  if (past !== null && timestamp - past < 200) {
    requestAnimationFrame(move);
    return;
  }

  past = timestamp;
  e.style.left = ++count + 'px';
  requestAnimationFrame(move);
};

requestAnimationFrame(move);
```

Try it in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/am9meqr7/).

---

Now my question is: *Which one performs better?*

---

My guess is, that if an interval is applicable, it will perform better. There aren't so many logical expressions to evaluate and so many calculations to do. But that's just a guess. So, are their any benefits of one way over the other?

Comment: I'm not sure what your code does but using requestAnimationFrame inside a setTimeout feels wrong. Is your question to find the interval between frames? You can use performance.now() to calculate sub ms timestamps and do t1-t0 = timeDifference, where t0 is performance.now() before and t1 is after.

Comment: The first one will run at 5fps, the later at ~60fps

Comment: @JonasW.they both run at 5fps. The second one checks if it's been 200ms before animating as well. It just runs more frequently, but without doing anything useful most of the time.

Comment: @TKoL Right, that is excatly my concern about the second example, which you see more often in tutorials.

Comment: If you only need an animation frame every 200ms, you're wasting compute time asking for it every time. As I said in my post, the structure of your first one is fine, but if you need to know the exact ms, you still have to calculate that with the passed timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

You should do the first one. However you shouldn't assume it will be exactly 200ms. If you need to know exactly how many milliseconds it's been, you must calculate it every time like in your second example, but keep using the structure of your first example.

The problem with the second example is that it calculates the new frames just as often as the first example, but it runs the function just to check that it doesn't need to run the function every other time it runs. Lots of wasted computation there.

You need to calculate the time elapsed (if you need accuracy) because the setTimeout combined with the requestAnimationFrame will not be guaranteed to run in 200ms. The requestAnimationFrame in particular will add time onto that if it feels it needs to before it's ready to give you permission to animate (which is basically what requestAnimationFrame is -- it's giving you permission to animate, saying 'I'm ready now').

Comment: Why? You should give some reasons for your judgement

Comment: You didn't answer the question: **Now my question is: _Which one performs better_?**